# The question states that the roots can only be imaginary but I think they are equal too

Tags: quadratics

> **Question Statement:-**
>
> If $p,q,r$ be in H.P. and $p$ and $r$ are of same sign, prove that the roots of the equation $px^2+2qx+r=0$ will be imaginary.

---

**My solution:-**

As $p,q,r$ are in H.P. then the relation b/w the three is as follows:
$$q=\dfrac{2pr}{p+r}$$

Now consider the discriminant of the equation $px^2+2qx+r=0$.

We get, $D=4q^2-4pr=4(q^2-pr)=4\left(\dfrac{4p^2r^2}{(p+r)^2}-pr\right)=-4pr\left(\dfrac{p-r}{p+r}\right)^2$

Now, as it is given that the sign of $p$ and $r$ is same, so $\boxed{pr\gt0}$ and as $p,q,r$ can be same too so we get $D\le0$

We can obviously see that the roots can be equal (and hence real too) or imaginary with the conditions given in the question.

Is it that the question misses to include the point that $p,q,r$ should be distinct.

Comment: Correct, I think it has missed the point, because if $p=q=r$  then the equation simplifies to $x^2+2x+1=0$, which has real solutions. However, if $p \neq r$ then the square term is non-zero, hence the discriminant is negative.

Comment: What is H.P. and 'are of same sign'?

Comment: What is H. P. ?!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think the equation that you wrote for the condition $p=q=r$ should be $x^2+2x+1=0$

Comment: @user350331 yes, thank you for pointing that out. But the solutions still remain real.

Comment: @5xum - HP stands for Harmonic Progression

Comment: @JanEerland- HP stands for Harmonic Progression

Answer (score 0):

For a quadratic equation:

$$\text{a}x^2+\text{b}x+\text{c}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}$$

So, when ($\text{r}=\text{c}$ and $\text{p}=\text{a}$):

$$\text{q}=\text{b}=\frac{4\text{a}\text{c}}{\text{a}+\text{c}}$$

We get, for the quadratic solution:

$$x=\frac{-\frac{4\text{a}\text{c}}{\text{a}+\text{c}}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{4\text{a}\text{c}}{\text{a}+\text{c}}\right)^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}=-\frac{2\text{c}}{\text{a}+\text{c}}\pm\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{\text{a}\text{c}\left(\text{a}-\text{c}\right)^2}{\left(\text{a}+\text{c}\right)^2}}}{\text{a}}$$